# Kestrel Customization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can't run my website when attempting to customize Kestrel by using the `UseKestrel` middleware in ASP.NET Core 2.2 (running on Windows 10).

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
            config.AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
                   {
                             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("the-key", "the-value")
                   })
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", reloadOnChange: true, optional: false)
                   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
        {
            options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

I didn't get an error, but my site won't load.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but shouldn't the optional JSON file name be created using the [`EnvironmentName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.internal.hostingenvironment.environmentname?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_Internal_HostingEnvironment_EnvironmentName) property with `$"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json"` instead of `$"appsettings.{env}.json"`?

Comment: You need to capture the error.  It is happening somewhere.  So you can enable the stdout in the web.config or look in the console where the kestrel is running. There has to be some output somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this and see what happens -

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                    
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseKestrel(options =>
              {
                  options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse(0.0.0.0), Convert.ToInt32(5000));
              })
                .UseUrls("0.0.0.0:5000")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
```